# What is the appropriate way to use matplotlib's xticks in combination with numpy's arange?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot some data that ranges on the x axis from 0 to 2.99998 that increments in units of .01. So, I'm trying to use matplotlib's xticks in tandem with numpy's arange to directly set my x ticks at .5 intervals to prevent having a tick for every point at the bottom of my plot. I have found numerous pages that describe how one can use something like `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 3.5, .5))` to accomplish this. To my understanding, this should produce ticks at `[0, .5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]`. However, I have a chronic problem where this results in a couple ticks that are crowded together rather than my intended outcome, regardless of the project. This is pictured here.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Your x-values don't seem to be the numbers you describe.  Maybe they are strings? Or something else? Could you add a complete reproducible example?  And an image of the plot before changing the xticks? Also note that the recommended way to modify the tick positions would be `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))`

Comment: Looking at that picture, you set up the xticks correctly, but your data is wrongly scaled on the x-axis.